# Boost Hana filter a constexpr tuple

Tags: c++, boost

Super basic question about Boost Hana.

From the [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) it seems I should be able to do the following:

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto a = boost::hana::make_tuple(-1, 4, 5, -4);
    constexpr auto b = boost::hana::filter(a, [](int elem) constexpr { boost::hana::bool_c<(elem > 0)>;});
}
```

However, I get

```
error: 'elem' is not a constant expression
```

which seems weird because I added `constexpr` wherever I could...

Is this at all possible? Or am I just missing something?

Note: I realize that you can achieve this with `constexpr` functions or something, but I would like to see how to do it with Hana as well, for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type must be statically deducible. However, you are returning different types depending on the argument.

You could do it, but not using `hana::filter` because that specifically moves into the runtime domain by putting the (statically known) tuple elements in (runtime) function arguments.

As soon as your predicate depends on more than *statically known* information (i.e. the types of the elements), it won't be constantly evaluated. The examples document how it could be used:

```
static_assert(hana::filter(hana::make_tuple(1, 2.0, 3, 4.0), is_integral) == hana::make_tuple(1, 3), "");
static_assert(hana::filter(hana::just(3), is_integral) == hana::just(3), "");
BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(hana::filter(hana::just(3.0), is_integral) == hana::nothing);
```

On the other hand, you can have your cake and eat it if you move the elements to the compile time domain:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b711a5d27deeddf3)**

```
constexpr auto a = hana::make_tuple(-1_c, 4_c, 5_c, -4_c);

constexpr auto b = hana::filter(                                                               //
    a,                                                                               //
    [](auto elem) constexpr { return std::integral_constant<bool, (elem() > 0)>{}; } //
);

std::cout << "a:" << hana::size(a) << "\n";
std::cout << "b:" << hana::size(b) << "\n";
```

Prints

```
a:4
b:2
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe add conversion from `int` to `hana::int_c` in the definition of the tuple?

Comment: You can use a hana::transform, no doubt. It'll be tedious, or perhaps someone with tons of  Hana fu that knows just how to find the sweet spots there. I see a route, but not one that is viable effort to include for this answer.